# Mac mini 2018 HDMI surround sound output

Tags: audio, mac-mini, hdmi, displayport

I have a new Mac mini 2018. I want to get surround sound over HDMI.

I have a receiver that is capable of transmitting 5.1 surround sound to my speakers, and HDMI video to my projector. I have confirmed that this is possible using alternative hardware (e.g. Windows PC).

When I connect my Mac mini to the receiver, I get video to the projector and sound to the speakers. However, the sound is only 2 channel stereo.

I have tried using the `Audio MIDI Setup` app to configure the audio. I can choose `5.1 Surround` as speaker configuration, but when I test that setup, sound is only output through the two front stereo speakers.

Strangely, the Audio MDID Setup app identifies my audio as `DisplayPort`, even though it should be HDMI.

[image: DisplayPort in Audio MIDI Setup app]

In the `Output` tab of Sound settings, the port is also shown as DisplayPort, no other options available

[image: Sound Output settings - DisplayPort]

Also a bit strange, in the `Sound Effects` tab of the Sound settings, I can choose `EPSON PJ` for `Play sound effects through`, but `Output volume` is disabled.

[image: Play sound effects through EPSON PJ]

I am running the currently latest macOS, Mojave 10.14.1. My receiver is a SONY STR-DN1040 AV-receiver. My projector is an Epson EH-TW9200

Comment: A couple of things to check... see if [if available] 7.1 output works. Sometimes what is considered sides in 7.1 is actually the rears - so there are no speakers connected as 'sides'. Secondly, what are you playing back from? Apps like VLC sometimes have to be switched to "Built-in Digital (Encoded Output)" before they will correctly transmit more than stereo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I managed to get 5.1 surround to work!

The solution was to configure the SONY Receiver to accept `A.F.D. AUTO`, which

> Presets the sound as it was recorded/ encoded without adding any
>   surround effects.

according to [the manual](https://www.sony.co.uk/electronics/support/res/manuals/4454/44544434M.pdf).